# Video parameters for best web scrolling performance

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

There is web application which provides next workflow. User uploads video -> backend(by using ffmpeg) transform this video for smaller size(320x240) -> web browser plays transformed video. Key feature of this application should be excellent scrolling possibility of  video by progress bar. I mean that video should be scrolled as smoothly as possible (without any jumps) when user moves progress bar position back and forward.

I thought that small size of video helps to provide good scrolling possibility. But that's incorrect. I have 2 different videos, one scrolling perfect(as I want), second has same resolotion(320x240), but it is scrolling with jumps and breaks.

By ffprobe I compared both videos and I have next results:

Video 1(good scrolling):

```
libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'spacetestSMALL_512kb.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    title           : small test video - http://www.archive.org/details/alanoakleysmalltestvideo
    encoder         : Lavf51.10.0
    comment         : license:  http://www.copyright.gov/
  Duration: 00:00:48.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 555 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240, 505 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 45 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Video 2(bad scrolling):

```
libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'e10b1c93-5325-4500-ae7c-12ccd0f617bd.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.5.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 428 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 391 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

What is the key parameter of video which provide possibility for good scrolling in web browser?